# How to access spring.application.instance_id programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have the following content in my "applicationname.yml" file of my Spring Boot/Cloud application. How can i get the value of spring.application.instance_id in my java code ?  This "applicationname.yml" file is hosted in the 'Spring Cloud Config Server'.

```
eureka:
  password: password
  client:
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${vcap.services.${PREFIX:}eureka.credentials.uri:http://user:password@localhost:8761}/eureka/
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: ${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${server.port}}}
```

I have a java class where i am trying to access this variable's value using the @Value annotation and it gives me an error. Here is what i have to get and print the value in the java class

```
@Value("${eureka.instance.instanceId}")
private String EinstanceId;

@Value("${spring.application.instance_id}")
private String SinstanceId;
```

***Error Message***:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.citigroup.ccp.psg.error.PSGErrorFilter.instanceId; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'eureka.instance.instanceId' in string value "${eureka.instance.instanceId}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'eureka.instance.instanceId' in string value "${eureka.instance.instanceId}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:801)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 51 more
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message or unexpected behavior or something? Clearly what you have isn't doing what you want it to, but it would really help to know what it *is* doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss `metadata` block. Use:

```
@Value("${eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId}") String instanceId;
```

As far as I know there is no instance_id property in spring.application namespace.

Comment: bingo !!! it worked. where can i see, what are all the other attributes available under this metadataMap ?

Comment: metaDataMap is let say hashmap of properties. You can put there anything you want and it will be visible to other services which uses yours. instanceId is special here - it need to be unique in order to be able to find this service instance in eureka. Hard to explain in couple sentences :) please take a look at docs: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html

Comment: + if you ever need to find some class to which .yml is mapped you can search "@ConfigurationProperties("eureka.instance")" in spring cloud sources. In this case its EurekaInstanceConfigBean.java

Comment: Further to this, `spring.application.instance_id` is _only_ set automatically when running on Cloud Foundry.  Otherwise you should use some other value which is what this does `${spring.application.instance_id:${server.port}}` - use the property if set, fall back to `server.port` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `@Value` annotation with Spring Expression Language

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

//...

    @Value("${spring.application.instance_id}")
    private String instanceId;

//...
```

Comment: am getting an error message saying Could not resolve placeholder 'eureka.instance.instanceId' in string value "${spring.application.instance_id}"  , what could be the reason ? or fix this error ?

Comment: I think it should be `eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId`

Comment: Any other ideas on this? I also get Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.application.instance_id' in value "${spring.application.instance_id}". I put it in my controller